# CSS Filter Doesn't Work Well Cross-Browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I need to put a red badge on top of an image and it must be cross-browser and different Windows versions.

I've added the following CSS classes, tested it on IE7, IE8 (XP) and IE9 (Win7), as well as Chrome and Firefox, and it looked good:

```
.ie9 .gradient{
    filter: none;
}

.badge {
    background: #f8b3b7; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f8b3b7 0%, #cc0103 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f8b3b7), color-stop(100%,#cc0103)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f8b3b7 0%,#cc0103 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f8b3b7 0%,#cc0103 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f8b3b7 0%,#cc0103 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top bottom,  #f8b3b7 0%,#cc0103 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8b3b7', endColorstr='#cc0103',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 12px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}
```

The HTML contains:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
    ...
<div id="iconContainer">
    <div class="badge gradient">!</div>
</div>
```

However, I've been reported that on some variations (apparently IE9 on Win7, not sure if 32bit or 64bit) it doesn't work and instead of the red-colored badge, only its white border is seen. The content is transparent instead of red.

Since I'm having trouble reproduce the bug, I was wondering whether it might be related to the specific browser's settings. Could it be? If so - which settings? Or perhaps to the OS version (32/64bit).
Any other suggestion on what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: CSS rendering should only be browser-dependent. Perhaps they have problems loading some CSS files, perhaps it reacts to browser width, perhaps javascript is kicking in too soon (if so, post it)?

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for replying, but I can't point my finger at the root cause. I do know that the CSS is loaded (the badge's border is visible, as well as the image on which the badge should appear). And I don't know how JavaScript is related here.

Comment: I've found an environment in which the problem is reproducible - IE8 on a Vista 32bit (though not sure this is the only environment on which the bug occurs). Anyway, removing the line `background: url(...)` seems to solve it. I did some tests on Chrome and FF as well and it looks fine. What's the purpose of this line and for which browsers it's intended? And what happens when 2 rules in the CSS seem to collide, like the aforementioned line and the one above it (`background: #f8b3b7;`)

Comment: `background:url(...)` sets an image background (here, using a data-url). When two rules for the same property exist in the same ruleset (selector), the last one that's understood and supported by the browser applies. Here, the image background applies when the browse does not understand the linear gradient.

Comment: Thanks. I got to the conclusion that in the specific problematic environment, none of the `*linear-gradient` rules is understood/applied by the browser, so the fallback is the upper line: `background: url(...)`. I need to fix the image in the URL (will use a real image there), though I would be very happy to understand why the heck none of those `linear-gradient` rules is satisfied in some IE environments. BTW, there was a typo above, I wrote `top bottom` instead of `to bottom` but that still doesn't cause this rule to apply.

Comment: I suggest using [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) to do gradients in IE6-9 -- it lets you use standard CSS gradient for IE and avoids all the issues with the `filter` style.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the shorthand 'background' for the gradients, which overwrites the background as a whole and when a browser encounters an invalid parameter, it will render it transparent. You should use background-image instead

You should use this piece of code instead, and edit it to your liking (for IE filters if that's what you want):

```
.box_gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Chrome, Safari 4+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

Taken from [css3please.com](http://css3please.com).

Comment: Also take a look at [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) – then you can write one `background-image` property that'll take care of all modern browsers. You'll just need to add the `filter` property for older versions of IE.